# How to remove warning in echoing a string constant in PHP

Tags: php

I declared a string constant named LABTITLE. When I tried to echo it in the title tag and run the code, the title of the webpage shows a warning. Is there something wrong with my code?

Our professor specifically instructed to print the Title in this way.

The Title tag:

```
<title>
    <?php
    echo constant("LABTITLE");
    ?>
</title>
```

The PHP code:

```
<?php
define("LABTITLE", "Laboratory Activity No. 2");
?>
```

Then whenever I run, this shows in the Title tab:

  **Warning** : constant(): Couldn't find constant LABTITLE in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Lab2\index.php** on line **12**

Comment: Where is the constant defined? Most likely you are not including the necessary file. The call to `define` needs to be in the same file, or included in the file calling `constant`. http://codepad.org/NqpQcbS5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define Your constant first then you can get value. looks like you are using constant value before you define.

```
<?php
define("LABTITLE", "Laboratory Activity No. 2");
?>
<title>
    <?php
    echo constant("LABTITLE");
    ?>
</title>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked now. I moved the <title> tag from the <head> to the <body> after the PHP section. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead you could directly use

```
<title>
    <?php
    echo LABTITLE;
    ?>
</title>
```

given following is included.

```
<?php
define("LABTITLE", "Laboratory Activity No. 2");
?>
```

Comment: have you test your code? how to get value of constant before you defining

Comment: Yes  its is well written that code will work given following is included.

Comment: make a php file set your code and check browser bar title